# Retrieve from package.xml listview

Tags: metadata-api, list-view, package.xml

I am trying to retrieve a ListView from Event object in my sandbox but I am not able to do it.
I can see it perfectly on workbench website. Sharing settings are set in "All users can see this list view". I have downloaded other listViews from account or opportunity without any problems. I can see also in VS Code, that I don´t have any listview folder in the Event object as I have in Account for example, but I have more than 5 different listViews.

My package.xml file

```
<types>
        <members>Event.Planned_Sales_Calls_Next_2_Weeks</members>
        <members>Opportunity.Opportunities_0_Closing_Next_30_Days</members>
        <members>Account.My_Accounts_Top_Activity</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
</types>
```

Which is working perfectly for the opportunity and account listViews but not for the Event one.

Screenshot from workbench:

[image]